# How to avoid emacs pop-up security warning for code eval

Tags: org-mode, warning, eval, security

How to disable this pop-up warning for orgmode commands such as:

```
shell:ls *.org
```

For which I would wish just to click once? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(setq org-confirm-shell-link-function nil)`

But:

> Shell links can be dangerous: just think about a link
>
> ```
> [[shell:rm -rf ~/*][Google Search]]
> ```
>
> This link would show up in your Org document as "Google Search",
> but really it would remove your entire home directory.
> Therefore we advise against setting this variable to nil.
> Just change it to ‘y-or-n-p’ if you want to confirm with a
> single keystroke rather than having to type "yes".

Cf. `C-h f org-confirm-shell-link-function`

See also `org-link-shell-skip-confirm-regexp`. You can allow specific commands through it. But beware of the possibility of a command like `ls *.org && rm -rf ~/*`: `^ls.*` is obviously not enough.

Comment: Very useful and nice explanation.

Comment: However, those links do not run independent from clicking. So one must still click. Is there the option to avoid the warning per buffer?

Comment: @Adelita I'm not sure what do you mean by running links independently. Do you want to run all shell links on the buffer ? Or one link, but asynchronously ? Or maybe both ? BTW, you can also press `C-c C-o` on the link instead of clicking at it. For the latter question, you can set `org-confirm-shell-link-function` locally so that it works per buffer. Cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44021603/8274517) to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I was looking for.